# AWS - Configuring Lambda Destinations with SNS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm trying to configure an AWS Lambda function to pipe its output into an SNS notification, but it doesn't seem to work.  The function executes successfully in the Lambda console and I can see the output is correct, but SNS never seems to be getting notified or publishing anything.  I'm working with Terraform to stand up my infra, here is the Terraform code I'm using, maybe someone can help me out:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_apigateway_to_sns_function" {
  filename = "../node/lambda.zip"
  function_name = "LambdaPublishToSns"
  handler = "index.snsHandler"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_apigateway_to_sns_execution_role.arn
  runtime = "nodejs12.x"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_apigateway_to_sns_execution_role" {
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "apigateway_to_sns_sns_full_access" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSNSFullAccess"
  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_apigateway_to_sns_execution_role.name
}

resource "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" "example" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_apigateway_to_sns_function.arn

  destination_config {
    on_success {
      destination = aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn
    }

    on_failure {
      destination = aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my Lambda function code (in NodeJS):

```
exports.snsHandler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: event.body + " apigateway"
    );
}
```

(the function is supposed to take input from API Gateway, and whatever is in the body of the API Gateway request, just append "apigateway" to the end of it and pass the message on; I've tested the integration with API Gateway and that integration works perfectly)

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to get this to happen auto-magically through infrastructure config, but you sure could use the SDK *in the lambda code* to publish whatever you want to your target SNS topic

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Yeah, I was doing that previously and I know that works.  However I'm specifically trying to learn about Lambda Destinations so I'd like to use that specifically.